# react-hook-form onSubmit not triggered

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, react-hook-form

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import FileBase64 from "react-file-base64";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import { TextField, Select, Input, MenuItem, Button } from "@material-ui/core";
import { useForm, Controller } from "react-hook-form";
import { yupResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers/yup";
import * as yup from "yup";
import { updatePost } from "../actions/post";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  textField: {
    marginBottom: theme.spacing(2),
  },
  buttons: {
    marginTop: theme.spacing(2),
  },
}));

const tags = ["fun", "programming", "health", "science"];

const postSchema = yup.object().shape({
  title: yup.string().required(),
  subtitle: yup.string().required(),
  content: yup.string().min(20).required(),
  tag: yup.mixed().oneOf(tags),
});

const EditPostForm = ({ history, post, closeEditMode }) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const [file, setFile] = useState(post?.image);
  const { register, handleSubmit, control, errors, reset } = useForm({
    resolver: yupResolver(postSchema),
  });

  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    const updatedPost = {
      _id: post._id,
      ...data,
      image: file,
    };
    dispatch(updatePost(post._id, updatedPost));

    reset();
    setFile(null);
    closeEditMode();
  };

  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <div>
      <form noValidate autoComplete="off" onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        <TextField
          id="title"
          label="Başlık"
          name="title"
          variant="outlined"
          className={classes.textField}
          size="small"
          {...register('title')}
          error={errors?.title ? true : false}
          fullWidth
          defaultValue={post?.title}
        />
        <TextField
          id="subtitle"
          label="Alt Başlık"
          name="subtitle"
          variant="outlined"
          className={classes.textField}
          size="small"
          {...register('subtitle')}
          error={errors?.subtitle ? true : false}
          fullWidth
          defaultValue={post?.subtitle}
        />
          <Controller 
            render={({field}) => (
                <Select
                    {...field}
                    input={<Input />}
                    className={classes.textField}
                    fullWidth
                >
                    {
                        tags.map((tag, index) => (
                            <MenuItem {...field} key={index} value={tag}>
                                {tag}
                            </MenuItem>
                        ))
                    }
                </Select>
            )}
            name='tag'
            control={control}
            error={errors?.tag ? true : false}
            defaultValue={tags[0]}
        />
        <TextField
          id="content"
          label="İçerik"
          name="content"
          multiline
          size="small"
          {...register('content')}
          rows={16}
          className={classes.textField}
          variant="outlined"
          error={errors?.content ? true : false}
          fullWidth
          defaultValue={post?.content}
        />
        <FileBase64 multiple={false} onDone={({ base64 }) => setFile(base64)} />
        <div className={classes.buttons}>
          <Button color="primary" variant="outlined" onClick={closeEditMode}>
            Vazgeç
          </Button>{" "}
          <Button color="secondary" variant="outlined" type="submit" >
            Kaydet
          </Button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default EditPostForm;
```

I have EditPostForm component, component doesn't give any error but when I tried to submit my form onSubmit function is not triggered.

I used react-hook-form to create my form and I used material UI components inside form.
When I Click button which has type submit does not trigger onSubmit function which is called inside of handleSubmit. Why onSubmit is not triggered?

Comment: Can you please also post your yup schema?

Comment: The code seems fine, I think you are having an issue with your validations. When testing the application, you are probably typing less than 28 characters for the content field.  I suggest you add some messaging for better debugging.

Comment: This is because you have not correctly destructured ```errors``` from ```useForm``` hook,
```const { ...others , formState : {errors} } = useForm({... validation config...})```.

Answer (score 45):

`onSubmit` isn't triggered because you may have form errors

You can get `errors` from `formState` object (`const { formState } = useForm(...)`)
And then use `error={formState.errors?.content ? true : false}` in your code
https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/formstate

See an example here
https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-burnell-2yufj?file=/src/App.js

Comment: On that note if one's using resolvers, then it's worth checking if correct schema is used. I was modifying validation schema until I realized I forgot to update which schema the resolver was using.

Answer (score 9):

You need to pass **onSubmit** and **onError** both.

Like this:

```
onPress={handleSubmit(onSubmit, onErrors)}
```

Comment: Changing onPress to onSubmit worked for me.

Comment: Thanks a lot!  It helped me figure out

Answer (score 3):

For someone who doesn't get this resolved by other solutions mentioned here. Two other possible issues.

1. There was no `type="submit"` attribute in the `Button` component.
2. The html `form` element didn't have the input fields and button component in the actual dom. The form contents were rendered inside a modal div in a different node in the DOM tree. Even though we see the form contents as children of `FormProvider`, the actual DOM fields were rendered as portal.
   So, actual DOM looked like

React DOM

```js
const FormContent = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Fields />
      <Button />
    </>
  );
};

const CreateItemButton = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Button onClick={openModel}>Create</Button>
      <FormProvider methods={methods} onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        <Modal isOpen={isOpen} onClose={closeModal}>
          <FormContent />
        </Modal>
      </FormProvider>
    </>
  );
};
```

HTML: (Actual DOM)

```html
<!-- actual page -->
<button>Create</button>
<form></form>

<!-- somewhere down the line as portal -->
<div class="modal">
  <input />
  <input />
  <button />
</div>
```

Comment: this one is the best answer

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same error, the problem was that, my register were Boolean and my input was string, and since the value was not required It didn't show errors until I figure out the problem and change register from Boolean to string

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, react hook form would not trigger the `submitHandler` if there are still errors within the `formState.errors` object. It would automatically go to the error handler of the `handleSubmit` parameters.
I have done a makeshift workaround that would ignore this case:

```
  <FormProvider {...methods}>
  <Card className={classNames('p-0 md:py-2 lg:px-10', wrapperCardClass)}>
    <LoadHandler status={recordStatus} errors={recordErrors}>
      <form
        className="relative flex flex-col gap-4"
        onSubmit={(e) => {
          methods.clearErrors()
          methods.handleSubmit(onSubmit)(e)
        }
      >
```

This would clear the errors before handling the submit request. I've used this for my project which is all server-side validation.
Hope this answer helps!

Answer (score 0):

Basically the button submits only when all the validation conditions are met(if any) and if there are no field errors. So, its better to check if there are any errors being generated after filling all the fields or while clicking on submit.