# React Hook Form with Children in React Native

Tags: react-native, react-hook-form

I have a form with ~15 fields where each section is a unique child component. I want to know how to pass data between the parent form and child components(using `control` because this is react native)

Right now, I see the proper value for `testResult` in onSubmit logs but `data` is `undefined` for some reason. This means my parent form is somehow not picking up the value in the child.

Parent Form:

```
const Stepper = () => {
  const form = useForm({ defaultValues: {      
      testResult: "",    
      } 
    });

  const {    control,    handleSubmit,    formState: { errors },  } = form;
  const testResult = useWatch({ control, name: "testResult" });

  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    console.log("watched testResult value: ", testResult);
    console.log("form submission data: ", data);
  };
  
  return (
  <WaterStep form={form} />
  <Button onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit())} />
  )
}
```

Child component:

```
const WaterStep = ({ form }) => {
  const { control, formState: { errors }, } = form;

  return (
    <Controller
        name="testResult"
        control={control}
        rules={{
          maxLength: 3,
          required: true,
        }}
        render={({ field: onBlue, onChange, value }) => (
          <TextInput
            keyboardType="number-pad"
            maxLength={3}
            onBlur={onBlur}
            onChangeText={onChange}
            value={value}
          />
        )}
      />
)}
```

Here I'm trying the first approach this answer suggests, but I've also tried the second with `useFormContext()` in child https://stackoverflow.com/a/70603480/8561357

Additionally, must we use `control` in React Native? The examples that use `register` appear simpler, but the official docs are limited for React Native and only show use of `control`

Update: From Abe's answer, you can see that I'm getting undefined because I'm calling onSubmit callback in my submit button. I mistakenly did this because I wasn't seeing any data getting logged when passing onSubmit properly like this `handleSubmit(onSubmit)`. I still think my issue is that my child component's data isn't being tracked properly by the form in parent

Comment: @Muhammad Irvan Hermawan any insight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is most likely in this line:

`<Button onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit())} />`

Since you're executing the onSubmit callback, you're not allowing react-hook-forms to pass in the `data` from the form.  Try replacing it with the following

`<Button onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)} />`

Comment: I never call the onSubmit like I'm doing here but I wasn't getting data logged at all onSubmit so I tried this. Now I realize this onSubmit call is why data is returning undefined, but my problem of no data still persists

Comment: If you're not seeing data logged, that means that onSubmit isn't being called, which probably means there are errors that prevent the form from being finished.  onSubmit is only called when the form validates successfully.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67421601/react-hook-form-onsubmit-not-triggered

Comment: Hey, you're right @Abe- after further investigating, I can see that was my issue. No data being logged upon form submission due to an error with my custom button's onSubmit callback. Seeing data logged as `undefined` when I passed `onSubmit()` as a call, made me think I had at least solved my blank form data problem but I was mistaken

Comment: Right, exactly - you saw `undefined` because you invoked `onSubmit`!  react-hook-forms wasn't deciding whether to call it or not.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone still looking for guidance on using react-hook-form with child components, here's what I found out to work well:

Parent Component:

```
const Stepper = (props) => {
  const { ...methods } = useForm({
    defaultValues: {
      testResult: "",    
    },
  });

  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    console.log("form submission data: ", data);
  };
  const onError = (errors, e) => {
    return console.log("form submission errors: ", errors);
  };
return (
  <FormProvider {...methods}>
      <WaterStep
        name="testResult"
        rules={{
          maxLength: 3,
          required: true,
        }}
      />
  <Button onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)} />
  )
}
```

Child:

```
import { useFormContext, useController } from "react-hook-form";

const WaterStep = (props) => {
  const formContext = useFormContext();
  const { formState } = formContext;

  const { name, label, rules, defaultValue, ...inputProps } = props;

  const { field } = useController({ name, rules, defaultValue });

  if (!formContext || !name) {
    const msg = !formContext
      ? "Test Input must be wrapped by the FormProvider"
      : "Name must be defined";
    console.error(msg);
    return null;
  }
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>
        Test Input
        {formState.errors.testResult && <Text color="#F01313">*</Text>}
      </Text>
      <TextInput
        style={{
          ...(formState.errors.phTestResult && {
            borderColor: "#f009",
          }),
        }}
        placeholder="Test Value"
        keyboardType="number-pad"
        maxLength={3}
        onBlur={field.onBlur}
        onChangeText={field.onChange}
        value={field.value}
      />
    </View>
  );
};
```

Here's what we're doing:

1. Define `useForm()` in parent and de-structure all its methods
2. Wrap child in `<FormProvider>` component and pass `useForm`'s methods to this provider
3. Make sure to define `name` and `rules` as props for your child component so it can pass these to `useController()`
4. In your child component, define `useFormContext()` and de-structure your props
5. Get access to the `field` methods like `onChange, onBlur, value` by creating a controller. Pass those de-structured props to `useController()`

---

You can go to an arbitrary level of nested child, just wrap parents in a `<FormProvider>` component and pass `formContext` as prop.

In Ancestor:

```
...
const { ...methods } = useForm({
        defaultValues: {
          testResult: "",    
        },
      });
    
const onSubmit = (data) => {
   console.log("form submission data: ", data);
};
...
  <FormProvider {...methods}>
    <ChildOne/>
  </FormProvider>
```

In Parent:

```
const ChecklistSection = (props) => {    
  const formContext = useFormContext();
  const { formState } = formContext;

  return (
  <FormProvider {...formContext}>
    <WaterStep
    name="testResult"
    rules={{
      maxLength: 3,
      required: true,
    }}
  />
  </FormProvider>
)}
```

---

Thanks to https://echobind.com/post/react-hook-form-for-react-native (one of the only resources I found on using react-hook-form with nested components in react-native)

---

....
And a further evaluation of my blank submission data problem, if you missed it:

As Abe pointed out, the reason I didn't see data or errors being logged upon form submission was because `onSubmit` was not being called. This was because my custom submission button, which I didn't include in my original question for simplicity's sake, had a broken callback for a completion gesture. I thought I solved `onSubmit` not being called by passing it as a call `onSubmit()`, but I was going down the wrong track.